# Creating D2D1 Factory and Hwnd Render Target

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, direct2d

I successfully created an empty window that would open and sit there until I closed it. Next, I wanted to try using Direct 2-D to draw something simple to that window. I created a class that would initialize Direct 2-D and then draw to the window, but after I added this class, my window would no longer open. After fiddling around with it a bit, it is now opening but then freezing and I get a message saying "a problem occurred causing the program to misbehave," and a button to "close program."

The window went from not opening to opening and then giving me the error after I added the return false if not s_ok seen below

```
//creating factory
HRESULT d2dFactHRes = D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &Direct2DFactory);
    if (!S_OK)
        return false;

    //creating render target.
    HRESULT RenTargHRes = Direct2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_DEFAULT, D2D1::PixelFormat(), 0.0F, 0.0F, D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_USAGE_NONE, D2D1_FEATURE_LEVEL_DEFAULT), D2D1_HWND_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES(), &pRT);
    if (!S_OK)
        return false;
```

I put a break point to try and check the return value of the EndDraw() function, and when I started the debugger, I got an error saying "unhandled exception occured at 0x00E4264F, an access violation occurred while reading 0x00000000 from location 0xC0000005"

I think this error occurred in the BeginDraw function before it got to the break point.

```
void Graphics::BeginDraw()
{
    pRT->BeginDraw(); //pRT is pointer to render target.
}
```

I have no idea what this means. I assume something wasn't in memory that it was trying to read?

I'd appreciate any advice. Thanks.

Comment: Please construct a [mcve]. You're likely finding the solution to your issue while creating it. If you don't, it'll still make for a better question.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "...finding the solution to your issue while creating it." I've tried to only include code related to the problem, which I believe concerns the class.

Comment: Having a class `Graphics` adds nothing meaningful to illustrate the issue. Likewise, the implementation of `Graphics::Draw()` adds nothing to illustrate the issue. Keep removing pieces of code, until you have the **absolute minimum** of code required to still show the issue. I posted a link with instructions.

Comment: There is nothing in that block of code that would cause the window to not show up. The problem is likely elsewhere. Also it is **imperative** to check the return value of `EndDraw()`, because you may need to recreate your render target and all of the device-specific objects (like brushes). And you must also call `ValidateRect()` after a successful `EndDraw()`, because otherwise Windows will keep sending `WM_PAINT` messages.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that. I'm going to try to rework some stuff in the code and the question. Actually what's happening now is that the window opens, then another window pops up and says "a problem occurred causing the program to misbehave" with a button that says "close program".

Comment: Trying to write code by guessing isn't going to work out. `if (!S_OK)` is perfectly valid code, but doesn't do, what you think it does. Heed the compiler's warnings. Anyway, your code never even attempts to create a render target. A debugger would have **immediately** told you. Learn to use it.

Comment: Ok, well I'm still a student trying to learn and figure this out (so, the rudeness isn't necessary). But, I'll try and make better use of the debugger in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that (presumably) your initialization code never runs to completion. It's the `if (!S_OK) return false;` statement that bails out early, right after creating the device factory. `S_OK` is defined as 0, `!0` is always true (as your compiler warned you, in vain).

The net effect is, that `pRT` never gets a pointer assigned, and the first time you dereference it, the system pops up the access violation dialog.

What you need to do instead is evaluate the return values (`HRESULT`'s). In COM programming it is common to use the [SUCCEEDED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687197.aspx), and [FAILED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693474.aspx) macros, e.g.:

```
if ( FAILED( d2dFactHRes ) )
    return false;
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually found a problem in the arguments of the render target. After fixing that, I fixed the S_OK line and it is working now. I misunderstood what the S_OK was doing. " if (d2dFactHRes != S_OK) return false; " would also be ok right?

Comment: @kazama: In this particular case (if the documentation is accurate) that would be ok. However, there are 2^31 different success codes, and some COM implementations return success codes other than `S_OK`. Using the macros makes sure that you are dealing with all possible error/success codes (if that is required, as in this case).